# how to exit from chromecast connected in HDMI

Tags: javascript, smart-tv

I'm working on a programming project for smart tv LG, now I've connected my application with a ChromeCast HDMI but the problem I have is that when I click on the exit button I cannot leave chromeCast and launch my application again.

**JavaScript code:**

```js
// click sur un element (LG remote control)[lancer input(HDMI) après click sur bouton2]
function clickOnElement() {

  var keyInput = parseInt(focusedElementKeyboard.split("btn")[1]);

  // check if the button 2 that has the focus
  if (keyInput == 2) {
    //connect to  HDMI1
    hcap.externalinput.setCurrentExternalInput({
      "type": hcap.externalinput.ExternalInputType.HDMI,
      "index": 0,
      "onSuccess": function() {
          alert("onSuccess");
          hcap.mode.setHcapMode({
        "mode" : hcap.mode.HCAP_MODE_0,
        "onSuccess" : function() {
          alert("onSuccess HCAP Mode 1");      
         }, 
  "onFailure" : function(f) {
   alert("onFailure : errorMessage = " + f.errorMessage);
  }
 }); 
      },
      "onFailure": function(f) {
        alert("onFailure : errorMessage = " + f.errorMessage);
      }
    });

    return;
  }

}
```

I need to know how to exit from the chromeCast connected in HDMI, I just have connected to HDMI with the method hcap.mode.setHcapMode when I change mod1 to mod0, but I could not use the button PORTAL which is allowed by the mod0 and to make the latter has 1

```js
//manipulate keydown event (LG remote control)

function manageLauncherKeyDown(keyCode) {

  //alert(" SWITCH key Down event");
  switch (keyCode) {
    case hcap.key.Code.ENTER:
      clickOnElement();
      break;
    case hcap.key.Code.UP:
      goTo();
      break;
    case hcap.key.Code.DOWN:
      goTo();
      break;
    case hcap.key.Code.RIGHT:
      goTo();
      break;
    case hcap.key.Code.LEFT:
      goTo();
    case hcap.key.Code.PORTAL:
      exit(); //i have just change mod1 to mod0 but i can't use this key         
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please write down an explicit clear-cut question? You seem to have gone a long way in your code. Kudos for this. But now, you have to help us helping you!

Comment: Hi, I'm working on a programming application for smart tv LG,  I've connected my application with a ChromeCast HDMI but the problem I have is that when I connect to HDMI, my application stays connected. so i want to know how to quit the application when i connect to chromeCast  and how to exit from it, 
For that I tried to change the mod1 by mod0 with the function hcap.mode.setHcapMode, which helped me to quit my application and launch only chromCast, but I can not leave it, even if I tried to make the mod to 1 through the PORTAL button which allow by mod 0

Comment: Please edit your question to include all helpful details in it, like I just have done.